# Need help on Beauitful Soup re-iterating over table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.harness.org.au"

webpage_response = requests.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/tracks/', "html.parser")

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")

# only finding one track
# soup.table to find all links for days racing
#harness_table = soup.row
# scraps a href that is an incomplete URL that im trying to get to

tracks = soup.find(class_="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 content")

lists = []

links = tracks.find_all('a')

#Gets each track
for a in links:
    lists.append(base_url+a["href"])
for link in lists:
  webpage = requests.get(link)
  track = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
  Barriertable = track.select(".mBarrier")
  trackname = track.find(class_="pageTitle")
  try:
      track1 = trackname.get_text()
  except:
      print('No class="pageTitle" found.')
      track1 = ''
  for th in Barriertable:
      td = th.find_all('th')
      row = [i.text for i in td]
      print(track1, row)
```

Print each row. in table yet I'd like to do a couple things that I'm stuck on:

1. Where I have 'Starts' - iterate over table data stats
2. Where I have 'Wins' - iterate over table data stats

I tried a few different things with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to loop the table rows

`for tr in Barriertable.select('tr'):`   and you can simplify code with use of list comprehensions (also handle `th` and `td` at same time using css Or syntax). Use `Session` for efficiency of underling tcp re-use with multiple requests. You can get track links in a single list comprehension step by changing selector.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

base_url = "http://www.harness.org.au"

with requests.Session() as s:
    webpage_response = s.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/tracks/')
    soup = bs(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")
    links = [base_url + i['href'] for i in soup.select('h4 a')]

    for track in links:

        webpage = s.get(track)
        soup = bs(webpage.content, "html.parser")
        barrierTable = soup.select_one('.mBarrier')
        trackname = soup.select_one('.pageTitle')

        try:
            track1 = trackname.get_text()
        except:
            print('No class="pageTitle" found.')
            track1 = ''
        for tr in barrierTable.select('tr'):
            row = [i.text for i in tr.select('th,td')]
            print(track1, row)
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference here is since you are going after `<table>` tags, is to use pandas' `read_html()`, as it uses beautifulsoup under the hood and will do the work of parsing tables for you:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.harness.org.au"

webpage_response = requests.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/tracks/', "html.parser")

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")

# only finding one track
# soup.table to find all links for days racing
#harness_table = soup.row
# scraps a href that is an incomplete URL that im trying to get to

tracks = soup.find(class_="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 content")

lists = []

links = tracks.find_all('a')

#Gets each track
for a in links:
    lists.append(base_url+a["href"])

# track1 = []
#purpose - just to get track name before going over other data
for link in lists:
    webpage = requests.get(link)
    track = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
    trackname = track.find(class_="pageTitle")

    if 'itemprop' in links[lists.index(link)].attrs.keys():
        continue

    try:
        track1 = trackname.get_text()
    except:
        print ('No class="pageTitle" found.')
        track1 = ''

    barrierTable = track.find('div',{'class':'barrierStats'})
    barrierTable = pd.read_html(str(barrierTable))[0]

    if barrierTable.empty == True:
        barrierTable = 'No Barrier Data...'

    print('%s\n%s\n' %(track1, barrierTable) + '#'*70 + '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Albany
  Barrier   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
0  Starts  74  74  74  74  72  61  71  60  41  34
1    Wins  11  11   9  13   6   9   7   3   4   1
######################################################################

Albion Park
  Barrier     1     2     3     4     5  ...     8    9   10   11   12  13
0  Starts  1250  1250  1250  1250  1249  ...  1125  959  790  467  277   6
1    Wins   197   137   186   153   115  ...   100   73   77   39   17   0

[2 rows x 14 columns]
######################################################################

Albury
  Barrier   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
0  Starts  63  63  63  63  58  35  60  55  39  25   5
1    Wins  11   8   6  11   2   5   5  10   3   2   0
######################################################################

Ararat
  Barrier   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
0  Starts  34  34  34  34  32  31  23  24  16  11   6
1    Wins   2   3   3   9   3   5   3   3   1   1   1
######################################################################

Armidale
  Barrier   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
0  Starts  15  15  15  15  14  11  15  15  10   5
1    Wins   3   0   1   0   0   1   3   4   2   1
######################################################################

....
```